# Eigen matrix as default argument to a function

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I know for a fact that if I wanted to create a function that might or might not need to accept an Eigen dynamic double matrix, I need to define an empty dynamic matrix, say, somewhere before my function header is defined.

file.h

```
Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> EMPTY(0,0);

void myFunction(Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>& inputMatrix); 
void myFunction(Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>& inputMatrix=EMPTY);
```

file.cpp

```
void myFunction(Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>& inputMatrix) {
     // do something
}
```

However the reality is, i'm currently working with a templated class and a function in this class has an Eigen matrix as optional parameter. Something like this...

myClass.h

```
template<typename Number>
class myClass {
    void myFunction(Eigen::Matrix<Number, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>& inputMatrix);
};

#include "myClass.tpp"
```

I've included the implementation of this templated class in a separate tpp file so I can hopefully have multiple function declarations. How can I then in this case make my `inputMatrix` a optional parameter? I've tried to declare the empty matrix above the class definition but I need the template typename for it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case, you'd better create two methods. One with a real parameter and one without parameter with the parametrized call inside. Something like this:

```
template<typename Number>
class myClass {
    void myFunction(Eigen::Matrix<Number, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>& inputMatrix);
    void myFunction()
    {
        myFunction(EMPTY);
    }
};
```

Usually, overloaded methods are easier to understand and maintain.